# Find number of sorted arrays resulting from parent array after removing exactly one element at a time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Brute force approach would be to remove, one by one, each number at a time and check if resulting array is sorted and maintain count of such sorted arrays. This would take O(n^2) time.

Is there another way to find the count in time lesser than O(n^2)?

Note: need to find count only of such sorted arrays after removing exactly one element at a time.

Eg:

Input: [1 2 3 4 5 4]

Output: 2 ([1 2 3 4 4 ], [1 2 3 4 5])

Input: [1 2 3 4 2]

Output: 1 ([1 2 3 4])

Comment: Is it possible to have two decreasing pairs in an array, and have an answer greater than 0? (A decreasing pair is two adjacent elements in the array, where the larger is first.)

Comment: You only need to look for the violating element, eg the last element in your first example. And then also take the element at the index before that into account. If there are no violators, i.e. everything is sorted, you can choose any one element. If there are more than one, you can start branching for future passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* I have this down to O(n) time - the algorithm performs only a single pass through the list, checking each element once.

---

For each element:

- If the next element is greater than or equal to the current one, continue.
- If the next element is less than the current one...

  - (Set a failure bit. If the bit is already set, stop checking.)
  - If the element two indexes ahead of this one is sorted with respect to this one, it means we can omit the next element and still be sorted. Add a match.
  - If the element one index behind this one is sorted relative to the element one index ahead of this one, it means we can omit the current element and still be sorted. Add a match.

---

Once this is finished running, the code checks the fail bit.

- If the fail bit is not set, then everything was sorted, and the number of possible lists is equal to the number of elements in the list.
- If the fail bit is set, there was at one unsorted element. The number of matches was recorded.
- If the fail bit was set and the loop exited early, there were at least two unsorted elements - no matches were possible.

---

```
EXAMPLE - steps are in reverse order

STEP  1 3 4 6 5 7 8
7                 ^ 8<=(end), pass
6               ^ 7<=8, pass
5             ^ 5<=7, pass
4b          ^   ^ 6<=7, we can safely omit next element (5) - add match
4a        ^   ^ 4<=5, we can safely omit current element (6) - add match
4           ^ 6!<=5, set failure bit
3         ^ 4<=6, pass
2       ^ 3<=4, pass
1     ^ 1<=3, pass
```

---

Below is an implementation in cpp. Note that the vector is padded to avoid extra bounds-checking logic for the first or last elements.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

int main(void) {

  std::vector<int> invals;
  int temp = 0;

  //pad the vector to get around out-of-bounds checking
  invals.push_back(INT_MIN);
  invals.push_back(INT_MIN);

  //get user input
  std::cout << "enter vals, ctrl_d to calculate" << std::endl;

  while(std::cin >> temp) { invals.push_back(temp); }

  //padding
  invals.push_back(INT_MAX);
  invals.push_back(INT_MAX);

  int matches = 0;
  int fail = 0;
  for(int i = 2; i < invals.size() - 2; i++) {
    //sorted - continue
    if(invals[i] <= invals[i+1]) { continue; }

    //something was unsorted
    else {

      //there was already another unsorted element - this list cannot
      //be sorted by removing just 1 element. break and fail
      if(fail == 1) { fail = 2; break; }

      else {
        //set fail bit
        fail = 1;

        //check if the next element can be removed
        if(invals[i] <= invals[i+2]) { matches++; }

        //check if this element can be removed
        if(invals[i-1] <= invals[i+1]) { matches++; }
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout << "\n\nmatches: ";
  if(fail == 0) { std::cout << invals.size() - 4 << std::endl; }
  else if(fail == 1) { std::cout << matches << std::endl; }
  else if(fail == 2) { std::cout << 0 << std::endl; }

  return(0);

}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/DrearyFrostyElectricity)

Comment: Failure bit logic works but if we track decreasing pairs, and if count of such pairs is more than 1, then no solution is possible; if it's 0, then everything is sorted, solution is parent array size; if it's one, then either 1 or 2 sorted arrays can result. Does this logic seem fine?

Comment: @MushiMaster That sounds correct to me, I think the logic is fine. Just need to determine the number of matches if it's one descending pair.